# interpolate two sets of data with different numbers of points

Tags: python, interpolation

im trying to interpolate two sets of complicated data I cant figure out where i'm going wrong. where do you put how long the data lengths are?
is this possible with already loaded data? examples only have numbers

```
fig1 = plt.figure() 

#load data    
    data1 = np.loadtxt(open("296.csv","rb"),delimiter=",",usecols=(0,1))        
    shape = (np.shape(data1))
    (x,y)=shape 
    len1 = len(data1)
#define data
    trans1 = list()
    wavelength1 = list()
#get data from what row
    for i in range(0,x,1):   
        trans1.append(data1[i,1])
        wavelength1.append(data1[i,0])   

    data3 = np.loadtxt(open("300.csv","rb"),delimiter=",",usecols=(0,1))
    #skiprows=6
    shape = (np.shape(data3))
    (x,y)=shape 
    trans3 = list()
    wavelength3 = list()        
    for i in range(0,x,1):  
        trans3.append(data3[i,1])
        wavelength3.append(data3[i,0])
    len3 = len(data3)

    ax1 = plt.subplot(111)


    x1axis = wavelength1
    x2axis = wavelength2
    x3axis = wavelength3
    y1axis = trans1
    y2axis = trans2
    y3axis = trans3
    ax1.plot(x1axis,y1axis,'blue')
    ax1.plot(x2axis,y2axis,'purple')
    ax1.plot(x3axis,y3axis,'green')
    x = (wavelength1,trans1,len1)
#error with lengths ...
    y = (wavelength3,trans3,len3)
    f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
    ax1.axis([1.55,1.65,.9986,.9988])
```

Comment: Please post an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (emphasis **minimum**)

Comment: Be sure to specify what's not working and the expected output. It can also important to tag your question with the names of the major modules you're using like numpy, matplotlib, etc.